# What happens when you combine "use strict"; inside functions with "use strict"; in the global context?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function useStrict(){
            "use strict";
        }
            "use strict";
            foo=10;
            alert(foo);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Leads to no error. Conclusion: strict mode isn't activated. But if I remove the function definition:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
            "use strict";
            foo=10;
            alert(foo);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error. Conclusion: strict mode is activated. But if I remove the `"use strict"` line in the global context and keep the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function useStrict(){
            "use strict";
        }
        foo=10;
        alert(foo);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get no error. Conclusion: strict mode isn't activated. What is going on here?

It seems that when `"use strict";` is both in the global context and in a function, they cancel out, since when I remove the function, strict mode is indeed activated. But then, without the `"use strict";` line in the global context, but inside of the function, strict mode isn't activated, which to me is unexpected. How could they cancel out before if `"use strict";` inside of a function call doesn't activate strict mode on its own?

Comment: The `"use strict;"` expression must be the **first** thing in the `<script>` block or function. Redundant `"use strict";` statements do not "cancel out".

Answer (score 1):

Your first script, for context:

```
function useStrict() {
    "use strict";
}

"use strict";
foo = 10;
alert(foo);
```

`"use strict"` only has an effect at the top of a script. The `function useStrict()` before it makes it not at the top. If you move it to the top, it will work.

```
"use strict";

function useStrict() {
    "use strict";
}

foo = 10;
alert(foo);
```

Otherwise it has the same semantics as `"use mayonnaise"`.